# When should we use the "absolute" property in css?

Tags: html, css, absolute

When is recommended to use "absolute" property in css, I mean, why don't you use the "relative" alignment, because the absolute position will differ on different resolutions and will always look different on other displays. I want to know when and why you should use absolute, an example could do the job.

Comment: Well, you use it whenever you need to. There's no one right answer. Perhaps some example might help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position#Examples

Comment: If you don't know why, you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`absolute` is just as "variable" as `relative`, screen parameters make no difference.

Since I develop games, I use `absolute` a LOT. It is very useful within `relative` containers to position UI elements. in fact, I'm working on a Facebook app right now and it had a fixed "canvas" size. Almost everything is absolutely-positioned for that.

Answer (score 1):

`position:relative` - sets the origin point for child elements

`position:absolute` - sets the position of the element in relation to the first positioned parent element

Relatively-positioned elements are no loner part of the layout/flow. This is useful for overlays, dialogs, tooltips and things like that. They act as their own "layer" without pushing around other content.

In general, you should not be using `position:relative` unless you also plan to use `position:absolute`.

Other tricks usually associated with `position:relative` can usually be accomplished using margins.

Comment: I believe an absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest _positioned_ ancestor, not necessary the "relatively-positioned" ancestor.

Comment: i know what absolute and relative means, but i don't know when to use them.. why can't i use relative all the time?

Comment: Because reletive elements take up space in the layout, making it difficult to layer and place other adjacent elements without nudging them around.